# Inputing string and printing them in random order

Tags: c, arrays, string, random, char

I'm having a little trouble getting my words to print out in random order. The 8 words that I insert will need to be printed out in random order. Right now I'm only able to generate a few of them in random order because it overwrites the previous space if the same number is generated twice. How can I eliminate this issue?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #define MAX 50

    int readLine(char string[]);

    int main(void)
    {
        int i;
        char str[8][MAX], temp[8][MAX];
        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        int r_num;

        printf("Enter 8 words:\n");

        for(i=0; i<8; ++i)
        {
            readLine(str[i]);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            r_num = rand()%8+1;
            strcpy(temp[r_num], str[i]);
        }

    printf("\nRandom order of words: \n");
    for(i=0; i<8; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", temp[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

int readLine(char string[])
{
    int ch;
    int i=0;
    while (isspace(ch = getchar()))
        ;
    while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)
    {
        if (i < MAX)
        {
            string[i++] = ch;
            ch = getchar();
        }
    }
    string[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of ways to shuffle data is picking from what is not selected yet.

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char str[8][MAX];
    int order[8]; /* order list */
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int r_num;

    printf("Enter 8 words:\n");

    for(i=0; i<8; ++i)
    {
        readLine(str[i]);
    }

    /* initialize order list */
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        order[i] = i;
    }
    for (i = 7; i > 0; i--) /* select from back to front */
    {
        int pos = rand() % (i + 1); /* pick one position randomly */
        /* pick selected element by swapping */
        int temp = order[pos];
        order[pos] = order[i];
        order[i] = temp;
    }

    printf("\nRandom order of words: \n");
    for(i=0; i<8; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", str[order[i]]); /* print strings in the shuffled order */
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks! this looks pretty simple solutions for me. What i dont get is that when you generate a random number it picks a range from i+1 ie from 0 to 8 the first time. The second time 0 to 7.. at least this is what im assuming its doing. Then how come it doesn't pick the same number twice? ie 5 the first time and then 5 the second time again?

Comment: @Alex When 5 is picked at the first time, 5 is moved to the back of the array by the swapping. so the candidates are [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6] for the second time and while *index* 5 can be chosen again, the *data* 5 won't be chosen again. `i` begin with 7 (number of elements - 1), so the range for the first iteration is 0 to 7 (non-negative number modulo (7+1)), not 0 to 8. The second time 0 to 6. Choosing from one candidate is obvious, so the condition `i > 0` can be used instead of `i >= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take care that you should not copy the same data into temp array.

You can check following simple logic,

1) Find the randno r_num

2) Swap. str[r_num] and str[maxlen]

3) Decrement max len by 1

4) Repeat

```
for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    // Commenting your code 
    //r_num = rand()%8+1;
    //strcpy(temp[r_num], str[i]);

    memset(temp1,0,sizeof(temp1));
    r_num = (rand()%(8-i))+1;
    if(r_num != i) // Do not swap if r_num is max
    {
        //swapping
        strcpy(temp1,str[r_num]);
        strcpy(str[r_num],str[7-i]);
        strcpy(str[7-i],temp1);
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Before storing a input line `string[i]` in a random output line `temp[r_num]`, you have just to verify if the selected output is free.

> First step, initialize the output array `temp[8][MAX]` from the first
>   loop:

```
for(i=0; i<8; ++i)
{
    strcpy(temp[i],""); // set each output line to free (empty).
    readLine(str[i]);
}
```

> Second step, loop on the randomize selector while the selected string
>   is not output:
>   The random index shall be from 0 to 7.

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    do {
        r_num = rand()%8; // index is between 0 and 7
    } while (strlen(temp[r_num])!=0); // output shall be free/empty
    strcpy(temp[r_num], str[i]);
}
```

Instead of:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        r_num = rand()%8+1; // error index start from 0
        strcpy(temp[r_num], str[i]);
    }
```